# How to count with filter django query?

Tags: django

I'm trying to get a list of latest 100 posts and also the aggregated count of approved, pending, and rejected posts for the user of that post.

**models.py**

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    POST_STATUSES = (
    ('A', 'Approved'),
    ('P', 'Pending'),
    ('R', 'Rejected')
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    status = models.ChoiceField(max_length=1, choices=POST_STATUSES)
```

**views.py**

```
def latest_posts(request)
    latest_100_posts = BlogPost.objects.all()[:100]
```

---

I get the latest 100 posts, now I want to get each author of the post and display their total Approved, Pending, Rejected count

- Title Of Post, Author1, 10, 5, 1
- Title Of Post2, Author2, 7, 3, 1
- Title Of Post3, Author1, 10, 5, 1
- ...

---

Some things I've thought about are looping through each of the 100 posts and returning the count, but it seems very inefficient

```
for post in latest_100_posts:
    approved_count = BlogPost.objects.filter(author=post.user,status='A').count()
    pending_count = BlogPost.objects.filter(author=post.user,status='P').count()
    rejected_count = BlogPost.objects.filter(author=post.user,status='R').count()
```

---

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I know about using aggregate Count but I'm not sure how to sub-filter on the status ChoiceField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this using [conditional aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation):

For that, lets add `related_name` in `BlogPost`.

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    POST_STATUSES = (
    ('A', 'Approved'),
    ('P', 'Pending'),
    ('R', 'Rejected')
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_posts")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    status = models.ChoiceField(max_length=1, choices=POST_STATUSES)
```

Then lets update the queryset:

```
from django.db.models import Count, Case, When, IntegerField

top_post_users = list(BlogPost.objects.values_list('auther_id', flat=True))[:100]
users = User.objects.filter(pk__in=top_post_users).annotate(approved_count=Count(Case(When(user_posts__status="A", then=1),output_field=IntegerField()))).annotate(pending_count=Count(Case(When(user_posts__status="P", then=1),output_field=IntegerField()))).annotate(reject_count=Count(Case(When(user_posts__status="R", then=1),output_field=IntegerField())))

users.values('approved_count', 'pending_count', 'reject_count')
```

Comment: Can you help me merge the queries together? It returns the user counts perfectly but I'm not sure how to get the title https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55268494/how-to-merge-two-querysets-django

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import Count

approved_count = BlogPost.objects.filter(author=post.user, status=‘A’).annotate(approved_count=Count(‘id’))
pending_count = BlogPost.objects.filter(author=post.user, status=‘P’).annotate(approved_count=Count(‘id’))
rejected_count = BlogPost.objects.filter(author=post.user, status=‘R’).annotate(approved_count=Count(‘id’))
```