# How to merge two querysets django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get a list of latest 100 posts and also the aggregated count of approved, pending, and rejected posts for the user of that post.

**models.py**

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    POST_STATUSES = (
                    ('A', 'Approved'),
                    ('P', 'Pending'),
                    ('R', 'Rejected')
                    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField()
    status = models.ChoiceField(max_length=1, choices=POST_STATUSES)
```

---

**views.py**

Now I'm getting the the aggregated count like so, but I'm confused on how to merge the count with the title of the posts

```
top_post_users = list(BlogPost.objects.values_list('user_id', flat=True))[:100]
users =  User.objects.filter(pk__in=top_post_users).annotate(approved_count=Count(Case(When(user_posts__status="A", then=1),output_field=IntegerField()))).annotate(pending_count=Count(Case(When(user_posts__status="P", then=1),output_field=IntegerField()))).annotate(reject_count=Count(Case(When(user_posts__status="R", then=1),output_field=IntegerField())))
users.values('approved_count', 'pending_count', 'reject_count')
```

---

This is the result I want:

- Title Of Post, Author1, 10, 5, 1
- Title Of Post2, Author2, 7, 3, 1
- Title Of Post3, Author1, 10, 5, 1

---

**How can I merge the returned counts with the titles?**

I know I could use a for loop and append each one, but efficiency wise I don't think this is the right way to do it. Is there a more efficient way using django database ORM?

I've tried this

users.values('title', approved_count', 'pending_count', 'reject_count')

...and that works, but it returns more than the latest 100 posts, so I think it's getting all the posts for those users and the aggregated count.

Comment: What is 10,5,1 etc here?

Comment: If you can cast the queryset into a different data structure, like a `list`, I'm pretty sure `pandas` has tools that would make this easier. Not sure offhand what they are though

Comment: @JPG Approved Count, Pending Count, Rejected Count

Comment: I suppose I could use pandas.. I roughly know how to merge using it, but I'd like to keep it as a database query operation @Green Cloak Guy

Answer (score 2):

Ultimately, you want a list of BlogPosts:

```
main_qs = BlogPost.objects
# add filters, ordering etc. of the posts
```

and you want to display not only the authors next to the title of the post but also enrich the author information with the annotated counts.

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Count

# you need subqueries to annotate the blog posts
base_sub_qs = BlogPost.objects.filter(author__pk=OuterRef('author__pk'))

# add subqueries for each count
main_qs = main_qs.annotate(
    user_approved_count=Subquery(base_sub_qs.filter(status="A").annotate(
            c=Count('*')).values('c'), output_field=IntegerField()),
    user_pending_count=Subquery(base_sub_qs.filter(status="P").annotate(
            c=Count('*')).values('c'), output_field=IntegerField()),
    user_rejected_count=Subquery(base_sub_qs.filter(status="R").annotate(
            c=Count('*')).values('c'), output_field=IntegerField()),
)
```

You can then access these in your template:

```
{% for post in posts %}
    {{ post.title }}
    {{ post.author.get_full_name }}
    approved: {{ post.user_approved_count }}
    pending: {{ post.user_pending_count }}
    rejected: {{ post.user_rejected_count }}
{% endfor %}
```

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions

Comment: I am getting an error: 'Query' object has no attribute 'contains_aggregate'

Comment: I've changed the code. Trying to convert my working code to your use case. I thought your code might allow a simpler version, but you still need `Subquery` to make the `OuterRef` work.

Comment: Now I am getting this: Subquery returns more than 1 row

Comment: `values('c')` is meant to prevent that. Please make sure that you have added it to all the subqueries.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I was confused, it looks right and makes sense logically, but its returning more than one row still...

Comment: To understand what is going on and to debug: turn on logging of your database (in postgres you do this in postgresql.conf in the data dir), copy the statement that is generated for this ORM call and paste it into the SQL client (e.g. psql). Then fix it until it works on the DB level. This should give you a hint what you need to change in Django.

Comment: I reviewed the SQL statement and the subquery is grouping by the id of the blogpost rather than the id of the user.